# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting this error in Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This error is referencing this line of my `main.js` file.  These two lines are both causing this error to happen:

```
jQuery("#signupfrm").fadeToggle('fast',function(){
jQuery("#loginfrm").fadeToggle('fast',function(){
```

I am getting this error when working on the website on my local computer, but it's from a theme I purchased that has a demo available online.

Here's a working copy of this same template:

https://www.whmcsdesigns.com/demo/cart.php?a=add&pid=1&systpl=flex

Just select "I will use my existing domain and update my nameservers" and enter any domain name.  You'll be taken to a page where personal info can be entered.  You will see that you have the option to select between "New Customer" and "Existing Customer".  It works at the link above.

However, on my local server it's not letting me switch between new and existing.  It just gives the error show above and is referencing those lines with `signupfrm` and `loginfrm`.

I'm guessing since it's working on the link aboving, those functions must be defined.  Can anyone else find where those are being defined at?

Comment: This could be a plethora of things. Have any more specific error logs?

Comment: Is there no way to find where those are being defined at the link above?  I was just thinking that perhaps I accidentally removed those functions during some heavy modifications...

Comment: You wouldn't have removed them unless you messed with jQuery itself, which odds are you didn't do. Check to make sure jQuery is properly installed.

Comment: Are you includign jquery

Comment: why not use $ instead of jQuery

Comment: Are you sure those jQuery constructors are actually finding the element and creating a jQuery object?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I guess it would be easier if I just uploaded my version so everyone can see.  I have a few more things to fix to make it operational but will post a link to it shortly to see if I can get some help fixing this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that I suspect to be the problem:

- jQuery hasn't been loaded correctly so the jQuery function can't be performed. It might not have been loading at all or it might be called $, but if other calls to jQuery work it should be OK.
- fadeToggle is a part of jQuery so I expect that to work if jQuery is loaded
  jQuery("#signupfrm").fadeToggle('fast',function(){
- sometimes if you load dynamically and you test on C:\ or whatever local path things don't work the same, especially AJAX calls. Set up a local webserver to work on always, just using localhost on a simple Apache is a good start

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess it would be easier if I just uploaded my version so everyone can see.  I have a few more things to fix to make it operational but will post a link to it shortly to see if I can get some help fixing this.  Thanks!